# Playing an item from a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, media, playlist

I'm trying to make my MediaPlayer play the item I click on the listbox.

But it's not working and I don't see why.

Here's the creation of my listbox: (I add the item when the open is executed)

```
    private void OpenExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Audio files (*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg)|*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg|Media files (*.avi;*.mp4;*.wmv)|*.avi;*.mp4;*.wmv|Image files (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
        MediaPlayer.Play();
        ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        var name = openFileDialog.FileName;
        item.Content = name;
        playlist.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

And then here's the function when you double click on an item in the listbox:

```
    private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
        MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(playlist.SelectedItem.ToString());
        MediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the output of playlist.SelectedItem.ToString() ? Are you sure it corresponds to the media's path?

Comment: I got something like that : System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: C:\Media\Test.mp4
This isn't right, right ? But then how could I do ?

Comment: You have System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem just before your path? Your player won't handle that. See my answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `playlist.SelectedItem.ToString()` statement doesn't give a well formatted path. Try this instead:

```
private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MediaPlayer.Stop();
    string mediaPath = ((ListBoxItem)playlist.SelectedValue).Content.ToString();
    MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(mediaPath);
    MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

To explain a little bit, your `playlist.SelectedValue` statement returns an object, that you have to cast to its original meaning which is ListBoxItem. Starting from this, you can then access your value path using Content property. Again, this is an object that you have to cast to its original meaning, which is a string (i.e: your string path).

Comment: I got a problem with GetItemText, do I need to do something special for it ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a method for ListBoxControl. I've updated my answer to make it work.

Comment: My bad! It was my fault, I did something wrong. Your answer is perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Once again, really thank you. I'm on this from a while now! THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating two List's One holding the name of the item, while the other holds it's directory.

You find the files directory by using `openFileDialog.SafeFileName`

When you need to play a file, play the SafeFileName.

**Your code would look a bit like this:**

```
listbox creation:`List safePlayList = new List();
private void OpenExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Audio files (*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg)|*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg|Media files (*.avi;*.mp4;*.wmv)|*.avi;*.mp4;*.wmv|Image files (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.SafeFileName);
        MediaPlayer.Play(); 
    ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        var name = openFileDialog.FileName;
    var safeName = openFileDialog.SafeFileName;
        item.Content = name;
        playlist.Items.Add(item);

    safePlayList.add(safeName);
    }
```

**And your listbox Double click would look like this:**

```
private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MediaPlayer.Stop();
    MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(safePlayList[playlist.SelectedIndex]);
    MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Hope this code works and *tweaking may be required* because I wrote this in Notepad and haven't tested it.